# Showing p-values in scientific notation with gtsummary::tbl_regression?

Tags: regression, gtsummary

Your help is most appreciated to include **p-values** for `gtsummary::tbl_regression` function in **scientific notation**. I am using big data and it would be really useful to show 3 **decimal points for p-values > 0.001** and **scientific notation for p-values <0.001**.

A representative example

```
# load packages
library(gtsummary)
theme_gtsummary_compact()

# linear model 
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + gear, data = mtcars %>% dplyr::mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)))

# regression table 
tbl_regression(mod1)
```

I wonder if it is possible to get the 2.06e-4, 5.76e-8, and 0.422 p-value notations for cyl 6, cyl 8, and gear, respectively.

```
summary(mod1)
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own function for the p-value format:

```
tbl_regression(
  mod1, 
  pvalue_fun = function(x) {
    if_else(
      is.na(x), 
      NA_character_,
      if_else(x < 0.001, format(x, digits = 3, scientific = TRUE), format(round(x, 3), scientific = F))
    )
  } 
)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. Can this be edited to show scientific notation only when the p-value is < 0.001?

Comment: Yah sure, you just need an if statement in the function. See the updated version.

Comment: Thanks. This works beautifully for the scientific notation, however, the else statement is not working for the p-values >0.001, see updated question.

Comment: I don't know the details for why `digits` doesn't work in all cases. Using `round` instead should do the trick. I updated my answer.