# How does one report exact p-values for p-values less than 0.001 in gtsummary?

Tags: gtsummary

I have quick, simple question. I am trying to figure out how I report exact p-values for extremely small p-values in gtsummary. The default for p-values less than 0.001  is simply to round them and indicate that they are "<0.001"; however, I am looking for a way to report the exact p-values with scientific notation or something similar. Additionally, when one currently tries to modify the significant digits using the "style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)" function, the maximum number of digits it allows one to report is 3 digits. Also, please note I am looking to report these p-values particularly for the output of a "tbl_regression" table. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can pass any function to `tbl_regression(pvalue_fun=)`, not just `style_pvalue()`. For example, you can use `tbl_regression(pvalue_fun = as.character)` to view the p-values to all their precision.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful. Is it possible to combine scientific notation with the exact output to make reporting the p-values a bit more manageable? Right now when I pass "as.character" through the table it reports an extremely long string of values, so would be helpful to still have rounding involved somewhat

Comment: Yeah, just search for your favorite scientific notation function in R and pass that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69843971/showing-p-values-in-scientific-notation-with-gtsummarytbl-regression